# Can not use same fixture in two different tests

Tags: mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I have two tests that patch the same function. If I run test by test everything works well. But if I run entire file the second test will fail due to it is unable to patch the function. And every other function patch will not work, just the first one.

I tried several approaches but without success.

```
def test_1(mocker):
    mocker.patch('package.class.function')
    response = client.get("/train/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    
def test_2(mocker):
    mocker.patch('package.class.function')
    response = client.get("/train/2")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Even if I use parametrize the case is the same, just the first one pass.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("id", [1,2])
def test_x(mocker, id):
    mocker.patch('package.class.function')
    response = client.get(f"/train/{id}")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I also tried this way

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_function(mocker):
    mocker.patch("package.class.function")

def test_1(mocker, mock_function):
    response = client.get("/train/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    
def test_2(mocker, mock_function):
    response = client.get("/train/2")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

but without success. I tried to put tests in class, defining different scope, ... no success.

How can I patch same function and use it in multiple tests?

Comment: *"But if I run entire file the second test will fail due to it is unable to patch the function."* What is the exact error you get? With `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")` your patching fixture should be invoked only once per the entire test set but you imply that you tried it so it's not clear why the patching itself would fail.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, just the test is failing because the function is not patched, it is executed as regular. So with scope="function" the function is patched only for the first test, every subsequent test works normally as if I didn't have a patch. If I change scope to 'session' I'm getting error `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture mocker with a session scoped request object`. I'm trying to create tests for fastapi endpoints.

Comment: I see. I didn't realise that *pytest-mock* has its `mocker` fixture scoped to function. You could rewrite `mock_function` to use `unittest.mock.patch` directly without using `mocker` fixture but considering what you said about the function silently not getting patched I have doubts it would help you because something strange is going on.